# c# use RemoveAt as function

Tags: c#, list

Can anyone help me?

I have a list (`listA`), and I have another one (`listB`)

I want to save all elements of `listA` in `listB` except the first element.

Example: if listA value is `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`, then listB is `{2, 3, 4, 5}` .

Now, I have this code:

```cs
listB = listA;
listB.RemoveAt(0);
```

But I want to write this code in one line; is there any way to doing that?

Comment: Just to make sure, you want `listA` to still contain this first value, right? If yes, then double-check what is the value of `listA` and `listB` after `RemoveAt` :)

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that! the listA's first elements disappears, too!

Comment: This is because `listB = listA` doesn't copy the list, it copies the reference to the same object. So, when you do `listB.RemoveAt(0)`, you remove the items from the original list :) You can use LINQ to copy the list without the first item. This is not the most performant, but the most C# idiomatic and nicest way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Skip` method to achive that.

```
var listB = listA.Skip(1).ToList();
```

It will skip the first element in the list and create a new `List`

Answer (score 0):

change the `listB = listA;` to

```cs
listB = listA.Skip(1).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is. You may use *System.Linq*'s [Enumerable.Skip](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netframework-4.8).

That would make your code:
`listB = listA.Skip(1).ToList();`